# Converting Date/Time string to Date/Time Value using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

so I'm confused as to how to take the auto-populated string "01/18/2021@19:00 (CST)" into a valid Date/Time format.

I know that I should be using Date formula but am unable to program this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Extra Homework:

Once this is done, I'd like google sheets to compare that time to real time and send me an email notifying me that the time is within 15 minutes of the noted time.

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far? Also. What are your expected results?

Comment: End Result:

I desire for Google sheets to notify me once a particular job is within 15 minutes of starting. 

I need to cell to automatically transfer a string into a valid date/time so that I can compare that to real time. 

The email aspect will obviously be secondary if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

If string is in the B2 Cell

```
=DATEVALUE(B2)+TIMEVALUE(B2)
```